# Why do I get "no match for call" on this code?

Tags: c++

Let's see I want to do this, i want to get the parent of a tree, then sum the nodes and putthe result in the parent, this is multithreaded. I'm using a queue to stare the nodes   thata can be sum, etc.

The problem I'm facing is this

```
error: no match for call to ‘(Triplets) (int&, int&, bool&, NodeT*&)’
```

The code is coming from is this

```
void find_triplets(NodeT *ptrRoot)
{
   if (ptrRoot != NULL)
    {
    find_triplets(ptrRoot->left);
    find_triplets(ptrRoot->right);

    cout << "find triplets and save them to the queue" << endl;
        cout << " we hit a hot spot is null the root, nothing to see here move along boys" << endl;

     if(ptrRoot->left != NULL && ptrRoot->right != NULL)
        {

        if (ptrRoot->left->done == true && ptrRoot->right->done == true)
        {
        cout << "we got one of 2 sons true so do something, this are the sons "
 << ptrRoot->left->key_value << " " << ptrRoot->right->key_value << endl;         

        cout << "sum them and put it in the father and set it to true " << endl;
        ptrRoot->key_value = ptrRoot->left->key_value + ptrRoot->right->key_value;
        ptrRoot->done = true;
        cout << "thread queue " << endl;
       triplet(ptrRoot->left->key_value, ptrRoot->right->key_value, ptrRoot->done, ptrRoot);
        qThreads.push(triplet);

        }
     }
        }
```

The triplet class is like so

```
class Triplets
{
public:
  int nVal1;
  int nVal2;
  NodeT *ptrNode;
  bool bUpdate;

  Triplets()
  {
    nVal2 = 0;
    nVal1 = 0;
    bUpdate = false;
    ptrNode = NULL;
  }

  ~Triplets()
  {
    delete ptrNode;
  }

  Triplets(int nVal1, int nVal2, bool bUpdate, NodeT *ptrNode)
  {
    this->nVal2 = nVal2;
    this->nVal1 = nVal1;
    this->bUpdate = bUpdate;
    this->ptrNode = ptrNode;
  }

  void form_triplet(int nval1, int nVal2, bool bUpdate, NodeT *ptrNode)
  {
    this->nVal2 = nVal2;
    this->nVal1 = nVal1;
    this->bUpdate = bUpdate;
    this->ptrNode = ptrNode;
  }
};
```

So what I want to do is to store the actual object in the queue to modify it, and don't make copies of it. Thanks

Comment: > triplet(ptrRoot->left->key_value, ptrRoot->right->key_value, ptrRoot->done, ptrRoot); -- What is it?

Comment: yea it appears that it was a dumb mistake it is Triplets not triplets,  well I fixed it so now the q is how do I give it a node to alter no to copy

Comment: Please ask new questions in separate posts. This question was about the compiler error, and you've gotten your answer. In your new question, please make sure to describe your program's desired behavior as it relates to its current behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `triplet` in your `find_triplets` function is a `Triplets` instance. The compiler interprets that line, therefore, as an attempt to invoke its `operator()` function using those four arguments, but your `Triplets` class has no such operator, so you get the error message reported above.

You probably meant either to declare another `Triplets` variable (named `triplet`), or to call `triplet.form_triplet` instead of `triplet.operator()`.

```
Triplets triplet(ptrRoot->left->key_value, ptrRoot->right->key_value, ptrRoot->done, ptrRoot);
// or
triplet.form_triplet(ptrRoot->left->key_value, ptrRoot->right->key_value, ptrRoot->done, ptrRoot);
```

Comment: Yes the constructor with those parameters is there on the triplets class.

Comment: I know, @User. That's why I suggested the constructor is what you meant to call. The constructor is called when creating a *new* instance, not when you already have one declared elsewhere. You need to include the type name if you want something to be interpreted as a declaration, as I show in my first line of code.